# OpenCV Template matching improper if region set using cvSetImageROI

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am trying to do match template using javaCV. Problem is that, if i set region using  `cvSetImageROI` then output is not proper, it shows rectangle anywhere in the resulted output area, but if `cvSetImageROI` is not used then results are proper, it shows desired output. 
Following is the code

```
public static void main(String c[]) {  
    IplImage src = cvLoadImage("D:\\opencvtest\\1.jpg", 0);  
    IplImage tmp = cvLoadImage("D:\\opencvtest\\close.png", 0);  
    IplImage result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src.width() -tmp.width()+1,src.height()-tmp.height() + 1),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
    cvZero(result);

   // cvSetImageROI(src, new CvRect(370, 175, 624, 398));
    //cvSetImageROI(result, new CvRect(370, 175, 624 - tmp.width() + 1, 398 - tmp.height() + 1));

    cvMatchTemplate(src, tmp, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

    double[] min_val = new double[2];
    double[] max_val = new double[2];
    CvPoint minLoc = new CvPoint();
    CvPoint maxLoc = new CvPoint();

    cvMinMaxLoc(result, min_val, max_val, minLoc, maxLoc,null);
    CvPoint point = new CvPoint();
    point.x(maxLoc.x() + tmp.width());
    point.y(maxLoc.y() + tmp.height());
    cvRectangle(src, maxLoc, point, CvScalar.GREEN, 2, 8, 0);
    cvShowImage("Lena Image", src);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(src);
    cvReleaseImage(tmp);
    cvReleaseImage(result);
}
```